# ¿Cómo se llama la forma derivada de boca en la palabra boquiabierto?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, palabras-raras, compuestos

*Boquiabierto* viene de *boca* (abierta). ¿Cómo se le nombra a la conversión

> *boca* → *boqui-*

o, en otras palabras, a la forma de *boqui*?

Comment: La forma *boqui-* se llama «elemento composicional*. Por lo tanto, podríamos llamarla la forma composición de *boca*, creo.

Comment: Ignoro si "boqui-" tiene una denominación como forma derivada de "boca". Lo que allí se produce es un fenómeno de diptongación para facilitar el fluir de la palabra y evitar el efecto cacofónico de dos aes consecutivas.

Comment: @c.p. Se me acaban de ocurrir otras dos palabras compuestas (también adjetivos) donde se produce un cambio similar: "carilindo" y "pelilargo". También tenemos el pájaro "petirrojo" (de pecho rojo). En fin, pareciera ser que la lengua en algún momento adoptó un mecanismo por el cual favoreció la presencia de la "i" como vocal que, por su suavidad, facilita la unión entre los dos elementos que componen esos adjetivos.

Comment: Otro caso similar es "cabizbajo". Nótese que el primer elemento siempre es el que pierde la autonomía por medio de esa conversión, y esto contribuye a la unidad de la nueva palabra.

Comment: He encontrado esto: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/por-qué-las-partes-del-cuerpo-toman-una-i-antes-de-componerlas-con-un-adjetiv que puede ser de interés.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que usted se refiere a las palabras compuestas formadas por un sustantivo y un verbo.

También existen otras estructuras compuestas, tales como:

> 1. Sustantivo + Sustantivo
>
>    Ej.: bocacalle, compraventa, mapamundi, hombre araña, niño prodigio, palabra clave.
>
> En este caso, algunas se escriben juntas y otras, separadas. En el
>   primer caso, para hacer el plural, se pluraliza la última palabra
>   (bocacalles, compraventas, mapamundis); en el segundo caso, se
>   pluraliza solamente la primera (hombres araña, niños prodigio,
>   palabras clave).
>
> 2. Sustantivo + Adjetivo
>
>    Ej.: pelirrojo, boquiabierta, padrenuestro, arco iris, camposanto.
> 3. Adjetivo + Sustantivo
>
>    Ej.: mediodía, altorrelieve, medianoche.
> 4. Verbo + Sustantivo
>
>    Ej.: correcaminos, sacacorchos, trabalenguas, pasatiempo, tentempié.
> 5. Adjetivo + Adjetivo
>
>    Ej.: altibajo, hispano parlante, iberoamericano, bienvenido.
> 6. Adverbio + Adjetivo
>
>    Ej.: bienvenido, malhablada, malquerida, bienamada.
> 7. Verbo +Verbo
>
>    Ej.: correveidile, tejemaneje.
> 8. Pronombre + Verbo
>
>    Ej.: cualquiera, quienquiera, quehacer.
>
>    Plurales: cualesquiera, quienesquiera (únicos casos en que la palabra compuesta se rompe para pluralizar la primera parte)

Fuente: http://salonhogar.net/salones/espanol/1-3/palabras_compuestas.htm

Comment: "abierto" no es verbo sino adjetivo.

Comment: Toda la razón. Fue un traspapelón mío por inprudente. Se agradece la observación.

Answer (score 1):

No parece que haya un término específico para este fenómeno (posiblemente una combinación de [apócope](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3ope) y [reducción de vocal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralizaci%C3%B3n_(fon%C3%A9tica))?), sin embargo la RAE dice esto con respecto al tema en su *Manual de la NGLE*:

> > **11.2.1f** Los segmentos de un compuesto aparecen a veces unidos por un elemento de enlace. Se usa la vocal -i- en los compuestos coordinativos formados con las pautas N-i-N (*ajiaceite*), V-i-V (*subibaja*) y A-i-A (*agridulce*), pero también en algunos subordinativos, como N-i-V (*perniquebrar*). En los compuestos formados por elementos grecolatinos (§ 11.8), el elemento de enlace suele ser -o- para los términos de origen griego (*cartógrafo, dermatólogo*) e -i- para los de origen latino (*apicultor, fratricida*).
> >
> > **11.4.1 Compuestos A-i-A**
> >     Se forman en español compuestos adjetivales combinando dos adjetivos, sea con vocal de enlace (*agridulce*) o sin ella (*sociocultural, sordomudo*). La pauta más productiva entre los primeros es la que combina dos adjetivos de color: *albiceleste, aurinegro, blanquiazul, rojinegro*. Estos compuestos no suelen designar colores intermedios, sino superpuestos de manera contigua o en patrones alternantes. Por el contrario, los compuestos coordinativos *agridulce, anchicorto, tontiloco,* etc., suelen referirse a cierta propiedad resultante de mezclar o combinar otras dos.
> >
> > **11.5.2 Adjetivos compuestos según la pauta N-i-A**
> >
> > **11.5.2a** La pauta N-i-A es la más productiva del español entre todas las que dan lugar a compuestos de sustantivo y adjetivo. A ella pertenecen barbilampiño, racicorto, cariacontecido, narilargo, ojizarco, pernilargo y otros muchos compuestos, casi todos adjetivos que se predican mayoritariamente de nombres de personas o animales. Se asimilan a este grupo el adjetivo cabizbajo y los que alternan entre la presencia y ausencia del segmento de enlace -i-, como *alablanco ~ aliblanco; cuelloalbo ~ cuellialbo; picoabierto ~ piquiabierto*. El adjetivo (a veces participio) presenta en ellos los rasgos morfológicos del grupo nominal del que se predica el compuesto, en lugar de los del sustantivo contenido en este. Así pues, *roto* en *manirroto* no concuerda en género con el sustantivo *mano*.
> >
> > N.- nombre
> >     V.- verbo
> >     A.- adjetivo

---

Unos ejemplos adicionales:

- -o > i

  - altibajo, anchicorto, blanquivioletas, albivioleta, callialto, clarividente, cuellilargo, culicagado, gallipavo, gualdinegro, manirroto, rojigualda
  - ajiaceite, ajicola, ajilimójili, ajipuerro
  - cultiparlar, cultipicaño
  - ojiazul, ojigarzo, ojizarco, ojiverde, ojinegro, ojimoreno, ojialegre, ojijunto, ojituerto
  - peliagudo, peliazabache, peliblanco, pelicorto, pelilargo, pelinegro, pelirrojo, pelirrubio
- -a > -i-

  - alicaído, aliquebrar, arquimesa, cartivana, cejijunto, coroliflora, perniquebrar, zanquivano
  - boquiabierta, boquirrubio, boquisucio
  - cabecicafé, cabeciduro
  - patiperro, patituerto
- -e > -i-

  - artimaña, voltiarepas
- -e + y > -i-

  - veintiuno, veintidós, ...
- - > -i-

  - calicanto, coliflor, crucigrama, cultalatiniparla

---

**Fuentes**

<sup>• https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/vocal-de-enlace-en-palabras-compuestas-maniobra-boquiabierto-pelirrojo-etc.2694772/?hl=es

• https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-term-designating-sound-change-for-words-from-dictionary-form-to-compound-words-and-to-what-degree-does-this-sound-change-exist-among-different-languages</sup>